# Ubuntu 18.04 log out user if display switchs off

Tags: suspend, display, logout

I have my ubuntu 18.04 plugged on a 4k Tv which will switch off randomly when no activity is seen. (I can't modifiy this).
If the monitor is switched off. Ubuntu will automaticly log the user out (session is still running)
When I restart the TV, the screen is back (music would still play) 
I have then to manually *ctrl + f1* to get back to login screen and re-log in.
I disabled everything related to display/power managment/Lid...etc and actually I have no idea what I should do to solve this.
*this is not happening on windows 
*Ubuntu 18.04 + nvidia prop. 396.54 /GT1030
Hope someone could help there!
Regards,
H.